# Block finalization stopped

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, kusama, substrate-parachain-template

I had setup the private network of 3/3 validators with 3 nodes(one node for one validator), after that I connected the fourth node to that private network and added the fourth validtor which goes in waiting state. After the completion of era I had increased the validator count, now my validator count is 4/4 everything is working fine.
Now, the issue is when I added more validators on fourth node and increase the validator count and make the network of 7/7 validtators, my block generation time is increased and block finalization is stopped.[image]

But if i am applying the process of one node for one validator and make the network of 7/7 validators everything is working fine.
Now I want to know that why this issue occurs when I added multiple validators from a single node.

Comment: Please add more detiald. How did you add the new validator? Did you insert the GRANDPA key correctly?

Comment: Firstly, I connected the node and inserted the gran,babe,imol and audi keys through RPC, after that from the same node I added more validators by inserting the rotate key. There was no issue when i added 2 or 3 validator from the same node through rotate key but when i added more than 3 validators from the same node I started getting the block generation and block finalization issue and **Yes I inserted the GRANDPA key correctly**

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart the node after inserting the GRANDPA key? I remember there is an issue about that.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/7268

---

No, you can not add multiple validators into a single node.

- https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/issues/663
- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/3324

Comment: Yes, I restarted the nodes and the blockchain is working fine but after adding more validators on a single node I can't restart it again because it will be an offence for the validator

Comment: Updated answer.